# Change distro - Ubuntu 22.04 to Debian 12

Tags: distributions, debian-installer

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a somewhat updated 7 year-old HP Laptop. It has 16GB of ram and 500GB SSD storage; an HDMI output connected to a 32" flatscreen at 720p; a wireless keyboard and mouse; and critical files backed up to another computer using Syncthing.

The 22.04 with Gnome desktop seems okay, but as my most used applications are Blender, Gimp and Libre Office Writer, I am more concerned with a distro's stability than I am with its 'nifty' features. I want to convert to Debian 12.

The SSD storage is partitioned pretty much the way 22.04's installer set it up. Following is the storage portion of the 'lsblk' output:

```
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part  
├─sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi  
├─sda3   8:3    0  28.6G  0 part /  
├─sda4   8:4    0 298.1G  0 part /home/warrensmailbox/fs  
└─sda5   8:5    0 138.6G  0 part /mnt
```

In installing 22.04, I turned over the entire SSD to the installer. It created sda1, sda2 and sda3 for the system components and sda4 for the storage area, which I have divided into sda4 and sda5, both of which are mounted as shown on the root tree.

I want to install Debian 12, using sda1, sda2 and sda3, reformatting them as necessary - the system root and the currently installed programs should all be on sda3 and I do not care about preserving any of this - but without disturbing the data partions, sda4 and sda5, which, if the installer has not done so, I will mount on the new root tree. (And yes, if necessary, I can make changes to 'fstab' that will properly check and mount them at boot time.)

Is this possible, and if so how do I do it? Is there a writeup that would explain in detail how I do this, and if so, where is it?

Comment: When installing debian, just do manual partitioning and do whatever you want on sda1-3 while leaving sda4-5 untouched (or just specify their mountpoints only).

Comment: Thank you 'annahri'. I did as you suggested and was able to get past that step. However, I was still unable to install Debian 12 due to another problem, which I explain in another post.